# TypeScript write "if" in short

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the code that sets a property only if the argument is truthy:

```
export class Vector {
    protected x: number = 0
    protected y: number = 0
    protected z: number = 0

    set(x?: number, y?: number, z?: number) {
        this.x = x ? x : this.x
        this.y = y ? y : this.y
        this.z = z ? z : this.z
    }
}
```

However, I don't want to provide a fallback value of the current value. Ideally, I want to just do nothing if the value is falsy, like this:

```
if (x) {
  this.x = x
}

if (x) {
  this.y = y
}

if (z) {
  this.z = z
}
```

… but I don't want to write it like this, it is not cool. I'm looking for something like this:

```
this.x = x ? x
this.y = y ? y
this.z = z ? z
```

Is there any similar syntax that does what I want?

Comment: `a ? a : b` is equivalent to `a || b` (unless `a` expression has side effects).

Comment: You could  also remove the set method and make your properties public and set them when they need to be different from default

Comment: Thank you for a comment!!! Is it possible to erase ":b"?  I want to do nothing if there wan no a. I don't want to do b.

Comment: What @raina77ow means is usage like this: `this.x = x || this.x`

Comment: `x && this.x = x; y && this.y = y;` etc.

Comment: um sorry I am not good at English(T____T).  I want to do this.x = x ? x :  doNothing(writeNothing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually `x && this.x=x` would be the shortest syntax to get this done.

However x, y and z are all numbers. It's a bit dangerous to use this short-hand syntax for numbers. Consider the case where set is called with x=0. `0 && this.x=x` would not execute this.x as 0 is falsey in Javascript. From reading your code this does not seem like what you want to achieve, instead you want to skip setting this.x in the case x is undefined.

In that case, I suggest the following code:

```
set(x?: number , y? : number , z? : number){
    typeof x === 'number' && (this.x = x);
    typeof y === 'number' && (this.y = y);
    typeof z === 'number' && (this.z = z);
}
```

That way your `set`-function will support sending 0 as an argument, which it currently does not.

Comment: OH!!! You are so smart to notice that 0 is false!!! Very good study for me.But VSCODE give me error.";" is required(T_T)

Comment: Can you see which line you're required to add ;?

Comment: I add message to you on the question!

Comment: Huh I suppose typescript is a bit strict on using && in this way. Try putting paranthesis around the final statement: `typeof x === 'number' && (this.x = x);`

Comment: Yeah just tested it, seems to run correctly in typescript with paranthesis around the assignment. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Oh!!! No error!!!! I think this is the coolest way!!!!! Thank you so much , handsome 
 man!!!

Comment: The OP's message was edited out of the question. The code that produced the error was: `typeof x === 'number' && this.x = x;` (screenshot of the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2ryk.png)

Answer (score 2):

A clean way to write your method is

```
set(x?: number , y? : number , z? : number){
  this.x = x || this.x;
  this.y = y || this.y;
  this.z = z || this.z;
}
```

An other way is

```
set(x?: number , y? : number , z? : number){
  x && this.x = x;
  y && this.y = y;
  z && this.z = z;
}
```

But, as @Lars Holdaas already mentioned, this will not support the falsy values (like `0` or `""`). 
The generic way to solve this is by writing a validation or filter function to tell if the value is
actually truly for that parameter or not.

```
// returns `true` if x is a number
const n = x => typeof n === 'number';

set(x?: number , y? : number , z? : number){
  n(x) && this.x = x;
  n(y) && this.y = y;
  n(z) && this.z = z;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from other answers, you have three more options:

- Use `if` one-liner:

  ```
  if (x) this.x = x
  if (y) this.y = y
  if (z) this.z = z
  ```
- Use [`??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)  operator (it wasn't available in 2018, when the question was asked):

  ```
  this.x = x ?? this.x
  this.y = y ?? this.y
  this.z = z ?? this.z
  ```
- Use [default values for optional parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters):

  ```
  export class Vector {
      protected x: number = 0
      protected y: number = 0
      protected z: number = 0

      set(x = this.x, y = this.y, z = this.z) {
          this.x = x
          this.y = y
          this.z = z
      }
  }
  ```